# Derivitive of $e^{-x^2}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am currently re-learning high school/university calculus for a project that I am working on. I know that the derivitive of the above function is as shown below:
$$ -2 \cdot x \cdot e^{-x^2} $$

I can get at this solution using the chain rule:
$$ g(x) = f(h(x) $$
$$ g^{'}(x) = f^{'}(h(x))  \cdot  h^{'}(x) $$

However, when I write $ e^{-x^2} $ as
$$ \frac{1}{e^{x^2}} $$

and then apply the quotient rule, I get the following:

$$ g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{h(x)} $$
$$ g^{'}(x) = f^{'}(x) \cdot h(x) - f(x) \cdot h^{'}(x) $$

Apply this to my fraction I get:
$$ 0 \cdot e^{x^2} - e^{x^2}  \cdot  2 \cdot x $$
which is
$$ -2 \cdot x \cdot e^{x^2} $$

which is not the correct solution.

Am I missing something here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You forgot to divide by $(h(x))^2$:
$$g'(x)=\frac{f'(x)h(x)-f(x)h'(x)}{(h(x))^2}$$

Comment: The quotient rule you wrote down $g'(x) = f'(x)h(x) - f(x)h'(x)$ can't be right. What if $f(x)=1$ and $h(x) = x$ (so $g(x) = \frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: Thanks guys for the super fast reply. Yes, I did miss the denominator!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the quotient rule is

$$g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{h(x)}\implies g^{'}(x) = \frac{f^{'}(x)\cdot h(x) - f(x)\cdot h^{'}(x)}{[h(x)]^2}
$$

and since $f(x)=1$ and $f'(x)=0$ we have

$$g^{'}(x) = -\frac{h^{'}(x)}{[h(x)]^2}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! I missed the denominator.

Comment: @KLD'Souza I see! You are welcome, Bye!

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align} g(x) &= f(x) (h(x))^{\bbox[yellow]{-1}}\\
g'(x) &=f'(x) (h(x))^{\bbox[yellow]{-1}}  -f(x) (h(x))^{\bbox[yellow]{-2}} \bbox[yellow]{h'(x)} \end{align}